# Making jquery animation larger

Tags: jquery, animation, tweak

So I have been playing around with jquery animation and I have got it working using this method:

```
$(function() {
    $("#div3").animate(
        {top : "+=100"}, 500, function() {}
    );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dT9Yk/
My problem is it doesn't fall very far, I was wondering if there is a way to tweak to make it fall from top of the page kind of like:

http://texts.com/

Thank You!

Comment: its already falling from the top of the page in your fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fresheyeball/WjSJ9/)

```
$(function() {
    $('#div3')
    .css({
        // position the element off the top of the page
        top : ($('#div3').height() * -1) - $('#div3').offset().top
    }).animate(
        // animate to its natural resting place
        {top : 0}, 500, function() {}
    );
});
```

Comment: If my answer worked for you, please mark it accepted by clicking the checkmark next to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for a javascript version... but this can be done in CSS3. The idea is, if it can be done in CSS3, the best practice is to do it in CSS3, instead of javascript, and it will be faster too. :)

Note: faster as in, multiple CSS3 animations can be rendered at once, whereas javascript is single-threaded, and your logic will not continue until your animation in javascript is complete. Check your network speeds. It provides a faster website in the long-run.

http://codepen.io/Surakusa/pen/IGidB/

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/ CSS3 is not faster, or a better practice. Also -2000 is a magic number.

Comment: CSS is for Style. JavaScript should be only for the application logic... Generally you want to separate the application logic from the design & animation. Besides the CSS does perform much better especially on mobile devices.

Comment: -2000 is a magic number because css can't do the computation to determine the top of the page. As long as computation is necessary its logic and belongs in the logic layer. Also performance is not better, read the link from my previous post.

Comment: I see your point... However, I feel that this is purely situational, and up to the OP to decide what is more functional for him and his project. Which he chose yours anyway. :) but css has higher performance on mobile devices in terms of animation quality. Unless he is using GSAP but I doubt it. :)